# Gmaps API v3 -> infoWindow Content not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, infowindow

I am using Google Maps API v3 on my website and am trying to display markers from a markersArray.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var map;
var markersArray = [];
var infowindow;
var marker;
```

Then I am adding the markers in a loop to the array, calling the following function

```
function addMarker(location, name) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      company: name,
      title: name
   });
   markersArray.push(marker);
}
```

I am then trying to display the markers, which works like a charm, using this function:

```
function showOverlays() {
   if (markersArray) {
      for (var i in markersArray) {
         markersArray[i].setMap(map);
         google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray[i], 'click', function () {
         infowindow.setContent('<div style="height:300px; color:black">' + this.title +     '</div>');
         infowindow.open(map, this);
         });
      }
   }
}
```

Now comes my problem: The content of the infoWindows is not showing up. It opens up, but nothing is being displayed... 
If I put a 300px high div in it, the infoWindow actually resizes properly.... but no content is being displayed.

I've searched the web up and down and tried fiddling with it, but to no avail.

Has anybody experienced this and might give me a hint as to how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the error!

I've had the parent div (the DIV that the map canvas is in) styled with CSS... and set the z-index to 11. Apparently that prevented the content of the infowindow to be on top...

Hope that helps some people who might have done the same "mistake" :)

Thanks to kevmc for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the marker object doesn't have a title attribute, you need to retrieve it using `getTitle()`:

```
function showOverlays() {
   if (markersArray) {
      for (var i in markersArray) {
         markersArray[i].setMap(map);
         google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray[i], 'click', function () {
         infowindow.setContent('<div style="height:300px; color:black">' + this.getTitle() +     '</div>');
         infowindow.open(map, this);
         });
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi kevmc 

Thanks for your reply. When I insert an alert(this.title), even this.company, it does alert the correct value. The problem is really the content of the infoWindow not showing up / not displaying

Thank you.

Comment: If you use the web inspector on  the infowindow does it contain the expected markup? In other words is it an issue with the display of the window or the populating of it)

Comment: Hi Kev. Populating works, all content is available, I can alert() it without any problems. If I set infowindow.content to a div with 300px height, the infowindow actually resizes. But it id not displaying the text inside....

Comment: I just found the error! 

I've had the parent div (the DIV that the map canvas is in) styled with CSS... and set the z-index to 11. Apparently that prevented the content of the infowindow to be on top...

Hope that helps some people who might have done the same "mistake" :)

Thanks to kevmc for trying to help!